# How do I set up a proxy server using chromiumoxide?

Tags: rust, google-chrome-headless

I would like to use the crate [`chromiumoxide`](https://lib.rs/crates/chromiumoxide), which is a Chrome headless library in Rust.
How can I set a proxy server?

I read the doc, it seems like it's possible to do, but there is no example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this solution:

```
    let (mut browser, mut handler) = chromiumoxide::browser::Browser::launch(
        chromiumoxide::browser::BrowserConfig::builder()
            .no_sandbox()
            .args(vec!["--proxy-server=http=your-proxy.com:12321"])
            .build()
            .unwrap(),
    )
    .await?;
```

In the docs it mentioned this link: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-createBrowserContext

and is talking about:

```
proxyServer string
   optional Proxy server, similar to the one passed to --proxy-server
```

So I checked how to add arguments and there we go, it worked :)

EDIT: later i found another way:

```
let custom_browser_context = CreateBrowserContextParamsBuilder::default()
        .proxy_server("https=your-proxy.com:12321")
        .proxy_bypass_list("")
        .build();

let browser_context_id = browser
        .create_browser_context(custom_browser_context)
        .await?;

let target_params = CreateTargetParamsBuilder::default()
        .browser_context_id(browser_context_id)
        .url("about:blank")
        .build()
        .unwrap();

let page = browser.new_page(target_params).await?;
```

Note the proxy url pattern, read more here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings/